# AngularJS : Not able to access controller's scope variable inside $scope.$on

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am trying to access scope variable inside `$scope.$on` but it returns `undefined`, but if I use a normal variable it is working fine.

```
Example: 

app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
 this.a = "hello";
 var b = "hi";
 // some code

 $scope.$on('someEvent',function(scope,ele,attrs){
  console.log(this.a); // prints 'undefined'
  console.log(b);  //prints 'hi'
 });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your callback for `$on`, the value of `this` will be that callback. And since you haven't defined any property with name `a` in that call back, it will be `undefined`.

```
app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
 this.a = "hello";
 var b = "hi";
 // some code
 var that = this; // <<<<<<<<< 
 $scope.$on('someEvent',function(scope,ele,attrs){
  console.log(that.a); // prints hello
  console.log(b);  //prints 'hi'
 });
});
```

Comment: Yup, a rookie mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you should use `$scope.a` instead of `this.a`. also, `b` is used wrong as well.

your code should look like this:

```
app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
 $scope.a = "hello";
 $scope.b = "hi";
 // some code

 $scope.$on('someEvent',function(scope,ele,attrs){
  console.log($scope.a); 
  console.log($scope.b); 
 });
});
```

hope that helps.

Comment: Please update the comment in `console.log($scope.a);` to show `prints hello`

Comment: I am intentionally using 'this' to use ' controller as' syntax, hence do not want to use $scope.